A 70's/80's movie about a psychologist/psychiatrist and his life
He is in his 40's/early 50's, His father is a famous psychologist who writes best sellers and scorns him. He has troubles with his wife (maybe divorced?). One of his patients is an old cab driver that started hallucinating while driving, but in the end (really small spoiler since it's a secondary story) it turns out that the new paint/cleaning material in his cab is causing this effect. 
I was almost sure that the cab driver is Walter Matthau, but imdb brought nothing up. Maybe his image will ring someone's bell. 
In my memory it is a "small" movie, maybe even only for TV, where nothing really big happens, but it made me feel great and I would love to see if it has the same effect now...

This sounds like the TV movie Private Sessions from 1985, which was basically an unpicked TV pilot about a psychotherapist (Mike Farrell) who visits his patients and gets involved in their lives. One of them is a seemingly sane cab driver who has auditory hallucinations played by Tom Bosley (from Happy Days, among other things), who does bear a slight resemblance to Walter Matthau. It also stars Kelly McGillis as a rich nymphomaniac. Here's the DVD cover:


Thanks, I would have never found out about this without you, it's a bit too different from everything I wrote, funny how the mind works. Sorry for not responding sooner. Didn't get the notification for some reason.  Too bad they didn't pick the pilot. Now I'm going to find and watch this again at last, hopefully it's as good as I remember.
